# Qual o maior número. Não consigo entender o que está faltando?

Tags: java

Estou fazendo alguns exercícios de laço for para aplicar o que aprendi. Neste clássico exercício de solicitar 10 números para o usuário e mostrar no final qual é o maior.
Fiz assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TheBiggerNumber{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Double[] numbers = new Double[10];
        Double theBigNumber = 1.0;
        Double lessNumber = 0.0;
        Double comparativeNumber = 0.5;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println("Write 10 numbers randomly");
            numbers[i] = in.nextDouble();
            numbers[i] = comparativeNumber;
                if ( comparativeNumber > theBigNumber) {
                    theBigNumber = numbers[i];
                } else {
                        lessNumber = numbers[i];
                }
        }
        System.out.println("The Bigger number is: " + theBigNumber );
    } //end method main
} //end class
```

O programa compila e roda, porém o resultado não incrementa o theBigNumber, maior número fica sendo sempre oq declarei para o theBigNumber.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O objetivo do exercicio é mostrar o maior de 10 numeros digitados apenas? Da pra fazer sem utilizar 2/3 desse codigo ai.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na linha

```
numbers[i] = comparativeNumber;
```

Você está atribuindo o valor 0.5 à o número na posição i do vetor e não atribuindo à comparativeNumber o valor da i-ésima posição. Como 0.5 < 1, o valor de theBigNumber nunca altera.

Comment: Valeu Yan. Resolveu.

Comment: @SalatielAizza se a resposta solucionou seu problema, clique no V verdinho ao lado dela para marcar como aceita e resolvida.